# Converting XML to HTML in NodeJs using LibXSLT(throws has no method 'apply' error)

Tags: xml, node.js, xslt, libxslt

Anybody worked on XML to HTML transform  in Nodejs, Iam getting "has no method 'apply'"error

```
var fs = require('fs');   
var libxslt = require('libxslt');   
var libxmljs = require('libxmljs');   


var docSource = fs.readFileSync('Hello.xml', 'utf8');    
var stylesheetSource = fs.readFileSync('Hello.xsl', 'utf8');    
var stylesheet = libxmljs.parseXml(stylesheetSource);    
var result = stylesheet.apply(docSource);    
res.end(result);
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Object <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:template match="/hello-world"><HTML><HEAD><TITLE/></HEAD><BODY><H1><xsl:value-of select="greeting"/></H1>hello</BODY></HTML> </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
has no method 'apply'
   at C:\WEBROOT\DM\wwwRoot\hello\node_modules\Simple_Server.js:151:42
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you means your `stylesheet.apply(docSource)` failed because `stylesheet` doesn't have that method. Looking at [`the docs for xslt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libxslt) makes it pretty clear that `.apply` is on the results of `libxslt.parse`, not the result of `libxmljs.parseXml`. So you need to do:

```
var fs = require('fs');   
var libxslt = require('libxslt');   
var libxmljs = require('libxmljs');   

var docSource = fs.readFileSync('Hello.xml', 'utf8');    
var stylesheetSource = fs.readFileSync('Hello.xsl', 'utf8');  

var stylesheetObj = libxmljs.parseXml(stylesheetSource);
var doc = libxmljs.parseXml(docSource);

var stylesheet = libxslt.parse(stylesheetObj);
var result = stylesheet.apply(doc);    
res.end(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Loganfsmyth, I tried the same, but it does not return any results. I used with some sample xml and xsl

Comment: Execution does not go beyond the line "var stylesheetObj = libxmljs.parseXml(stylesheetSource);"

Comment: sorry, it did not pass this line var stylesheet = libxslt.parse(stylesheetObj);

Comment: `did not pass` is not a useful description. Was there an error message?

Comment: No there was no error logged in NodeJs error file, but it stops the server listening in the port. I used res.end() to find where it was stopping the execution and it was not going beyond the line var stylesheet = libxslt.parse(stylesheetObj);

Comment: Any suggestion on the same?

Comment: just use 
var stylesheet = libxslt.parse(stylesheetSource);  instead of 
var stylesheet = libxslt.parse(stylesheetObj);

@Narendran

Answer (score 0):

This syntax worked for me:

```
stylesheet.apply(doc,  function(err, result){   
console.log("result:",
    result.toString().replace(/^<\?xml version="1\.0" encoding="UTF-8"\?>\s+/, "")
    );
console.log("err:",err);
});
```